# Error response from docker daemon : failed to listen to abstract unix socket

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, devops

I work on ubuntu and suddenly all my docker containers exited with similar error like this:

> Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container 8a10cf84237e:
>   failed to listen to abstract unix socket
>   "/containerd-shim/moby/8a10cf84237ebf94f50b9418fdfc05c9c61a87d245db8d959f026d0a0f139557/shim.sock":
>   listen unix
>   /containerd-shim/moby/8a10cf84237ebf94f50b9418fdfc05c9c61a87d245db8d959f026d0a0f139557/shim.sock:
>   bind: address already in use: unknown

I tried restarting the service but the response from the daemon remains the same.

I do not want to delete the stopped containers nor i want to reinstall docker service.
Is there another way to solve this issue?

Comment: I had to redeploy my container. Then it was ok. A plain start of a stopped container was not working.